# How do I call the keyboard to show up or hide?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to show the keyboard up using an Activator Listener (if the phone gets shaken)

How do I call the keyboard using a command?

Comment: Do you have some kind of text input element?

Comment: Nope I have a game that have cheats that get activated when you type them in the keyboard inside the game (GTA)

Comment: 1)add any text field in UI 2) set its background,tint,textcolor to clear color, . 3) Add listener 4) Code [yourTextField becomeFirstResponder] 5) Add delegate for textfield 6) Implement textDidEndEditing and get entered cheat code 7) You get your cheat code in string

Comment: @ChanWarde but how do I add the Delegate on theos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIView* view = ...;
[view becomeFirstResponder];
```

or if that fails you could try:

```
[view performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

If you're interested in getting different types of keyboards, you could do something like this beforehand:

```
UItextField* textField = ...;
[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
```